# Onchange event for form fields on Reactjs page using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs

I need to track field changes on form built with Reactjs using javascript code that can be included in the page.

For non react pages, i can track field value changes using .change event from jQuery. How can I track the field value changes for React page? Is there any way to make it work with out any changes to existing react code and using external js file? Have been searching for the same but did not get how to interact with react components from javascript.

Answer (score 0):

React allows to have onChange handlers like this:

```
<input onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.sometext} />
```

If you want to be able to track this via jQuery, then you could tap into the componentDidMount method. This is a lifecycle method which is called when the component is mounted in the DOM.

```
componentDidMount() {
  $('input').change(doWhatever);
}
```

If you don't have access to the React component, then you should jQuery "on".

```
$('input').on('change', doWhatever);
```